# passing element id as parameter in appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, android-testing

I am new to Appium and trying android hybrid app testing with Java.
Is it possible to pass the xyz in the below example as a parameter to the method and how to do it?

eg:
dr.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("UiSelector().text(xyz)").click();

Also please point me out to any articles related to this topic.

Comment: What is xyz? Text of the elements, or some specific locator? You can find UIAutomator docs here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to pass text to your field you can use method `sendkeys();` for that.